# Get bytes from UIImage

Tags: ios4, uiimageview, uiimage, ipad

I have a UIImage object, but I need to access the bytes of the image.  I don't see any method in the class reference to do this, such as getBytes, etc.

This is coming back from a UIImagePicker, so I do not have a file path, just an instance of UIImage that contains the original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` will return `NSData*`'s that you can use to get the raw data

See docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation)